# Unable to add a new element in xml using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to add a new element in my xml file using powershell.

XML File (can't change the current content except adding a new element under Languages):

```
<UserSettings>
  <ApplicationIdentity version="16.0" />
  <Category name="License Header Manager_Languages" Category="{d1b5984c-1693-4f26-891e-0ba3bf5760b4}" Package="{4c570677-8476-4d33-bd0c-da36c89287c8}" RegisteredName="License Header Manager_Languages" PackageName="LicenseHeadersPackage">
    <PropertyValue name="LanguagesSerialized">&lt;Languages&gt;
  &lt;Language LineComment="//" BeginComment="/*" EndComment="*/" BeginRegion="#region" EndRegion="#endregion" SkipExpression=""&gt;
    &lt;Extensions&gt;
      &lt;Extension&gt;.cs&lt;/Extension&gt;
    &lt;/Extensions&gt;
  &lt;/Language&gt;
  &lt;Language LineComment="'" BeginComment="" EndComment="" BeginRegion="#Region" EndRegion="#End Region" SkipExpression=""&gt;
    &lt;Extensions&gt;
      &lt;Extension&gt;.vb&lt;/Extension&gt;
    &lt;/Extensions&gt;
  &lt;/Language&gt;
  &lt;/Languages&gt;
  </PropertyValue>
 </Category>
</UserSettings>
```

I'm trying to add add a new language with different extensions using following code

```
$file = "C:\Users\TempUser\Downloads\CurrentSettings.xml"

[xml]$xml = Get-Content $file

$extensions = @(
    ,@( @("#", "<#", "#>", ""), @(".ps1", ".psm1"))
    ,@( @("//", "/*", "*/", ""), @(".js", ".ts")))
$AttributeNames = @("LineComment", "BeginComment", "EndComment", "SkipExpression")

$xml.UserSettings.Category.PropertyValue | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "LanguagesSerialized" } | %{ 

    foreach ($elements in $extensions) {
        $lang = $xml.CreateElement("Language")   

        for ($j=0; $j -lt $AttributeNames.length; $j++) {
            $lang.SetAttribute($AttributeNames[$j], $elements[0][$j]) 
        }

        $extsElement = $lang.AppendChild($xml.CreateElement("Extensions"))
            
        foreach($ext in $elements[1]){
            $extElement = $extsElement.AppendChild($xml.CreateElement("Extension"))
            $extElement.AppendChild($xml.CreateTextNode($ext))
        }

        $_.AppendChild($lang)
    }
      
}

$xml.Save($file)
```

Expected result:

```
  &lt;Language LineComment="#" BeginComment="@*" EndComment="*@" BeginRegion="" EndRegion="" SkipExpression=""&gt;
    &lt;Extensions&gt;
      &lt;Extension&gt;.ps1&lt;/Extension&gt;
      &lt;Extension&gt;.psm1&lt;/Extension&gt;
    &lt;/Extensions&gt;
  &lt;/Language&gt;
```

Current Output in file (It adds the elements after Languages Tag):

```
&lt;/Language&gt;
&lt;/Languages&gt;<Language LineComment="#" BeginComment="<#" EndComment="#>" SkipExpression=""><Extensions><Extension>.ps1</Extension><Extension>.psm1</Extension></Extensions></Language><Language LineComment="//" BeginComment="/*" EndComment="*/" SkipExpression=""><Extensions><Extension>.js</Extension><Extension>.ts</Extension></Extensions></Language></PropertyValue>
    <PropertyValue name="Version">3.0.3</PropertyValue>
  </Category>
</UserSettings>
```

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Due to the sometimes huge differences between versions, especially core vs previous, use the tag indicating the version of PS instead of the general `powershell` tag.

Comment: When I execute your script I get following one more line in xml (I cannot put whole line). You have not specified what happens in your case.
<Language... .ps1 ...

Comment: @vish Yes it adds elements in one line. Somehow it appears outside of the Languages tag. I've added the current output.

Comment: There is no `Languages` node/tag in your XML. Check `$xml.UserSettings.Category.PropertyValue.'#text'` and `$xml.UserSettings.Category.PropertyValue.FirstChild.OuterXml`

Comment: @JosefZ it is part of the LanguagesSerialized PropertyValue `$xml.UserSettings.Category.PropertyValue | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "LanguagesSerialized" } | %{ $_.'#text' }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, guys! In my case, I can't encode and save as `<` and `>` in the file as that is another parser's job. I have to add the language before it goes to this parser. Previously, I was adding the child element outside the main Languages node. Here's the updated solution which adds the child language node into the main Languages node.

```
$file = "C:\Users\TempUser\Downloads\CurrentSettings.xml"
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $file
$extensions = @(
    ,@( @("#", "<#", "#>", ""), @(".ps1", ".psm1"))
    ,@( @("//", "/*", "*/", ""), @(".js", ".ts")))
$AttributeNames = @("LineComment", "BeginComment", "EndComment", "SkipExpression")

$xml.UserSettings.Category.PropertyValue | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "LanguagesSerialized" } | %{
    [xml]$Settings = $_.'#text' 

    foreach ($elements in $ExtensionDetails) {
        $lang = $Settings.CreateElement("Language")   
        for ($j=0; $j -lt $AttributeNames.length; $j++) {
            $lang.SetAttribute($AttributeNames[$j], $elements[0][$j]) 
        }

        $extsElement = $lang.AppendChild($Settings.CreateElement("Extensions")) 
        foreach($ext in $elements[1]){
            $extElement = $extsElement.AppendChild($Settings.CreateElement("Extension"))
            $extElement.AppendChild($Settings.CreateTextNode($ext))
        }
        $Settings.Languages.AppendChild($lang)
    } 
    $_.'#text' = $Settings.InnerXml
}

$xml.Save($file)
```

the output is

```
    ...
    ...
    &lt;/Language&gt;
    &lt;Language LineComment="#" BeginComment="@*" EndComment="*@" SkipExpression=""&gt;
    &lt;Extensions&gt;
        &lt;Extension&gt;.ps1&lt;/Extension&gt;
        &lt;Extension&gt;.psm1&lt;/Extension&gt;
    &lt;/Extensions&gt;
    &lt;/Language&gt;
    &lt;Language LineComment="//" BeginComment="/*" EndComment="*/" SkipExpression=""&gt;
    &lt;Extensions&gt;
        &lt;Extension&gt;.js&lt;/Extension&gt;
        &lt;Extension&gt;.ts&lt;/Extension&gt;
    &lt;/Extensions&gt;
    &lt;/Language&gt;
&lt;/Languages&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that your input xml is mixed - it has xml encoded and non-encoded characters (which is why you would not get child nodes of `PropertyValue` tag). I needed to change it to all xml non-encoded (< and >). After that it worked.

```
    <UserSettings>
    <ApplicationIdentity version="16.0" />
    <Category name="License Header Manager_Languages" Category="{d1b5984c-1693-4f26-891e-0ba3bf5760b4}" Package="{4c570677-8476-4d33-bd0c-da36c89287c8}" RegisteredName="License Header Manager_Languages" PackageName="LicenseHeadersPackage">
      <PropertyValue name="LanguagesSerialized">
        <Languages>
          <Language LineComment="//" BeginComment="/*" EndComment="*/" BeginRegion="#region" EndRegion="#endregion" SkipExpression="">
            <Extensions>
              <Extension>.cs</Extension>
            </Extensions>
          </Language>
          <Language LineComment="'" BeginComment="" EndComment="" BeginRegion="#Region" EndRegion="#End Region" SkipExpression="">
            <Extensions>
              <Extension>.vb</Extension>
            </Extensions>
          </Language>
        </Languages>
      </PropertyValue>
    </Category>
  </UserSettings>
```

In the process I modified your file to use `XPath` (just because it was easier for me):

```
      $file = "C:\temp\test.xml"

  [xml]$xml = Get-Content $file

  $extensions = @(
      ,@( @("#", "<#", "#>", ""), @(".ps1", ".psm1"))
      ,@( @("//", "/*", "*/", ""), @(".js", ".ts")))
  $AttributeNames = @("LineComment", "BeginComment", "EndComment", "SkipExpression")



      $languages = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//UserSettings/Category/PropertyValue[@name='LanguagesSerialized']/Languages")
      foreach ($elements in $extensions) {
         
          $lang = $xml.CreateElement("Language")   
          

          for ($j=0; $j -lt $AttributeNames.length; $j++) {
              $lang.SetAttribute($AttributeNames[$j], $elements[0][$j]) 
          }

          $extsElement = $lang.AppendChild($xml.CreateElement("Extensions"))
              
          foreach($ext in $elements[1]){
              $extElement = $extsElement.AppendChild($xml.CreateElement("Extension"))
              $extElement.AppendChild($xml.CreateTextNode($ext))
          }

           
           $languages.AppendChild($lang)
      }
      
        



  $xml.Save($file)
```